# Can't login using devise, migrating from restful_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, restful-authentication

I already migrating from restful_authentification to devise.
I follow every steps. I succeed sign up new user, confirm it.
also login with it's user. Everything is going right.

Until I found a bugs. That some of current user who already able to login with restful_authentification,
cannot login. It returns "Invalid username and password".

It is possible the reason is coursed from different password encryption system between restful_authentification and devise?

Or Devise didn't allow some characters on password?

Please help me? Its already 2 days find ways to resolve the issue

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not know restful_authentication, but i think you will have to reset the passwords of all the users that existed before. It is safe to assume that devise uses a different algorithm to encode the password.

When resetting the password from the console, you need to specify the `:password` and the `:password_confirmation`, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure Devise to use the `:restful_authentication_sha1` encryptor, the correct `pepper` and `stretches`? See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Migrate-from-restful_authentication-to-Devise